# TransactionManagementError when using data migrations to create initial data

Tags: django, django-1.7

I am trying to use Django 1.7's new data migrations to create initial data for my app.  I have Tag model with text (display text) and slug (unique) field.  When I try to do many Tag.objects.create() in a data migration then I am receiving this error:

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

I wonder if the transaction is aborting due to the IntegrityError (which I am intentionally ignoring.)  I am trying to replace the functionality of initial_data fixtures that are apparently deprecated in apps that use 1.7's new migrations.

my migrations file:

```
from django.db import models, migrations, IntegrityError

TAGS = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', ...]


def populate_initial_tags(apps, schema_editor):

    Tag = apps.get_model('widgets', 'Tag')

    for text in TAGS:
        try:
            Tag.objects.create(text=text)
        except IntegrityError:
            pass


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate_initial_tags)
    ]
```

my models

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    text = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Tag, dispatch_uid='update_tag_slug')
def update_tag_slug(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.slug = slugify(instance.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct, you can't simply ignore `IntegrityErrors` if you're inside a transaction (as migrations are). Instead do this:

```
for text in TAGS: 
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            Tag.objects.create(text=text)
    except IntegrityError:
        pass
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic).

Comment: thank you!  I don't see the transaction error anymore, but only the first Tag in the list is created.

Comment: @BenWilber: Hmm, my guess is that your slug is not getting set properly and so all subsequent `Tag` creations fail due to the slug unique constraint. You'll have to do some debugging to see what is happening.